# What means: "Gatsby, who represented everything for which I have an unaffected scorn."

Tags: meaning

The Great Gatsby by F. Scott Fitzgerald
This sentence: "Gatsby, who represented everything for which I have an unaffected scorn."
I don't understand because of words: "unaffected scorn" because of explanation in Cambridge online dictionary 
unaffected = not influenced, harmed, or interrupted in any way:
scorn = a very strong feeling of no respect for someone or something that you think is stupid or has no value
We have double negation:
not influenced
feeling of no respect
This "feeling" additionally make me confuse.

"not influenced feeling of no respect"

Can you explain to me with your words what means: "Gatsby, who represented everything for which I have an unaffected scorn."

Does it means "Gatsby, who represented everything what I don't respect."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have only found one meaning of unaffected. There are two:

> not influenced or changed in any way
>
> natural and sincere

[Unaffected (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/unaffected)

The words mean ""Gatsby, who represented everything for which I have a natural and sincere scorn." That is a scorn which is not pretended.

Comment: MichaelHarvey sorry but I do not understand you more then FSF.

Comment: If someone is doing something in an unaffected way, that means they are not pretending. If I am being unaffectedly happy, I am really happy. I am not pretending to be happy. If I have unaffected scorn for something, I really do feel that scorn. What don't you understand?

Comment: scorn? Does it means "Gatsby, who represented everything what I don't respect."

Comment: You already know what scorn means.

Comment: Note: You have to scroll down on the Cambridge page to see the second meaning. One can see both meanings more clearly on a site like [Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/unaffected). It also contains a definition with a nice synonym: _real_.

Comment: I would prefer to use Cambridge, Oxford, or Merriam-Webster, and read all of the definitions.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - I agree those are better dictionaries; however, I was wondering aloud if perhaps the OP missed the second definition in Cambridge because it's so easy to miss if you don't realize that additional definitions might be further down the page.

Answer (score 0):

Unaffected scorn:
Someone scorned me but I am not offended,
Someone scorned me but it doesn’t harm me,
I have some motivation to ignore the scorn which would make me feel bad.
Jesus said “scorning its shame,” in Hebrews 12:2